# how to use a php loop to update database?

Tags: php, database, loops, sql-update

I have look all over youtube and forms and I still can't find an answer that works. I want use a php loop to update database values. I need something like the two last loops below. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
             $heading[$i] = $_POST['heading' . $i];
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
             $des[$i] = $_POST['des' . $i];
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
             $update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE info1 SET heading[$i]='$heading[$i]' WHERE id= $i");
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
            $update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE info1 SET des[$i]='$des[$i]' WHERE id= $i");
        }

        header('Location: admin.php?success');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: stop assuming your queries succeeded. `if (!$update) { die(mysqli_error($connect)); }` so you can get told about your sql syntax errors.

Comment: I recommend doing more research on how to build modern applications with PHP. http://webdeveloper.gdemolished.com/stop-building-shitty-php-web-applications/

Comment: Unless you have a column named `des[0]`, - `des[100]`, these queries are going to fail

Comment: Also, consider using `name=heading[]` and `name=des[]` in your form, so that the `$_POST` variables will be arrays. Then you don't need the first two loops.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first [i] from your queries... try these

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
         $update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE info1 SET heading='$heading[$i]' WHERE id= $i");
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        $update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE info1 SET des='$des[$i]' WHERE id= $i");
  }
```